# iperf test - 10/100 router result the same as crossover on gigabit

Tags: networking

Was testing my speeds between my Ubuntu Server 14.04 and Windows 8.1 laptop. Ubuntu server had recently had a new 10/100/1000 gigabit card installed, all up and running perfectly and showing 10/100/100 in ifconfig.

So I did a iperf test through the 10/100 router and it was 86Mbits/s - ok good enough.

Then I connected directly to the server from the laptop using a cable, both ethenet cards gigabit configured and .... same result.... 86Mbits/s.

Are we looking at some form of software configuration needed here or am I doing something blatantly wrong??

---

Iperf Dump- Through 10/100 router

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.0.48, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 63.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.0.11 port 52708 connected with 192.168.0.48 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   103 MBytes  86.6 Mbits/sec
```

Iperf Dump - crossover,  both running 10/100/1000 gigabit cards

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.0.48, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 63.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.0.11 port 52744 connected with 192.168.0.48 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   104 MBytes  87.0 Mbits/sec
```

---

Ubuntu Server 14.04  - ethtool, lshw output

```
 server@mediaserver:~$ ethtool eth1
   Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Transmit-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
   Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
$ lshw -C network
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 10
       serial: 14:cc:20:04:1a:5e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.48 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:21 ioport:b800(size=256) memory:ff921000-ff9210ff memory:ff900000-ff91ffff
```

Windows 8.1 - wmic dump

```
C:\Users\Nick>wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed
Name                                Speed
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  100000000
```

What is the difference between size and capacity? Should the server be  1Gbits for size and capacity?

Comment: Use `ethtool` on the server or laptop to determine if the transmission rate is actually gigabit. Might be lower for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
>                                      100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
> ```

That means the other end of the connection is not advertising Gigabit capability. In this case, presumably that's your Windows 8 laptop, for which the Windows command output does show only 100 Mbit/s speed. Fix your laptop.

> What is the difference between size and capacity? Should the server be 1Gbits for size and capacity?

Size is actual connection speed, capacity is what the server can support on that interface. It would be 1G for both if both ends of the connection support 1G.

Comment: Hmmmmm.....thank you for that. Will try and examine that in more detail. After a few driver changes I am still encountering the same issue. Will test on another gigabit ethernet port and a new cat6 cable to rule out hardware and return a response.

Comment: You just keep racking them up!  ;-)